# Why is my request in GET, PUT, POST, and Delete slow

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laradock

So im running Laravel and React for this and i also use docker for running my laravel so specifically laradock its like this

[image]

my main problem is when im logging in or any type of request it takes too long for it to load or complete the request and also i run the own url in my localhost i use http://gjjsp-backend for this and i change the 127.0.0.1 to that url why it slow in completing the request

for context this is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Jbpp1zZPFG9/t31vnPRUBf1KPssoFZXMkbb5Qi26pMI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://gjjsp-backend
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000/
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://gjjsp-backend
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://gjjsp-backend
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_LIFETIME=30
```

Comment: Yeah dockerized laravel hosted in windows is slow. I don't know the specifics. This is not new issue. I suggest running dockerized laravel on wsl2 hosted in windows.

Comment: The path to the files of the laravel project. Are they in `/mnt/c/` ?  Or `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\` ? Also: consider not using docker desktop

Comment: I put my laravel inside the /var/www of my code when i type docker-compose exec workspace bash i download the laravel there

Comment: I hope you have wsl2 or real Linux. Log into your Linux and put your code in for example `/home/username/code/name-of-proiect`. Place your laradock in `/home/username/laradlck`. Adjust your .env file of Laradock. `docker-compose up your specific containers`, it will build and bring up your laradock containers. In windows hosts file put the IP address of your wsl2. It's much, much faster in the actual Linux of wsl2